# schedule tasks count in project server

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, calculated-column-formula, project-server

I want to write custom field formula in project server to get the tasks schedule count for each project and show it in project summary view in the project center

Please, Help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Unfortunately,** there is no `Count()` function to count the tasks in Project Enterprise Custom field formula.

Meanwhile, you can use **`[Task Count]`** field in your formula to get the count of all tasks,

[image]

> The only limitation of this workaround, you can't show this custom
>   field in Project Center views, but you can show it in Tasks view like
>   Task Summary.

Check the detail steps at [COUNT ALL TASKS IN PROJECT SERVER](https://blog.devoworx.net/2018/03/24/count-all-tasks-in-project-server/)